# Copying Multiple Sheets into a Data Grid View

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, datagridview, datagrid

How would I coppy data from multiple sheets into a data grid view. Currently I have it copying from 1 sheet like so:

```
string SheetName = this.cmbSheetNames.SelectedText.ToString();
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand =
                            new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + SheetName + "$]", objConn);
MyCommand.Fill(DS);
object Dt4 = DS.Tables[0];
dgvUploads.DataSource = Dt4;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string SheetName = this.cmbSheetNames.SelectedText.ToString();
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + SheetName + "$]", objConn);

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader reader = MyCommand.ExecuteReader();

dgvUploads.DataSource = reader;
dgvUploads.DataBind();
```